# Copy range of cells to subject of outlook mail

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

The function of this code is *to copy particular range of cells*, each cell (having codes like **1ML-234-1R**) and *place it in the body of outlook mail* (taken from Ron de Bruin Excel Automation code).

I want instead that the cells data goes into the **subject of mail** separated by **comma (,)** and does not leave any **spaces** before or after any cell data.

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Don't forget to copy the function RangetoHTML in the module.
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    'Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "faizanfarooque@hotmail.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Load Shed "
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

I am new to VBA and have tried Subject = RangetoHTML(rng) but it showed me this in the subject html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"

Comment: What did you try, or you would like us to do it for you?

Comment: Would it not just be `.Subject = "Load Shed, " & Trim(RangetoHTML(rng))`?  Or just `.Subject = "Load Shed, " & Trim(Range("A1"))` (or whatever your range is)?

Comment: @BruceWayne - that's kind of my point: it's pretty obvious what needs to be done.

Comment: well i am new to vba and  have tried it  Subject =  RangetoHTML(rng) but it showed me this in the subject  <html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"

Comment: @BruceWayne again same error is coming.

Comment: Ok that's the kind of thing which needs to be in the question: it's always helpful to describe what you already tried and what happened.  However -  you can't/shouldn't put HTML in the Subject: it's not going to render and may not even fit.  What you need is "RangeToCSV", not "RangeToHTML"

Comment: .Subject = Trim(RangeToCSV(rng))  used this but error sub or function not defined occurred.

Comment: No luck with it! please if anyone can help me out in this regard!

Comment: `RangeToCSV()` is a function that you write - or that you *at least try* to write: we're happy to help here but you need to take on some minimum baseline effort yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK then:

```
'.....
.Subject = RangeToCSV(rng)
'.....
```

Function:

```
Function RangeToCSV(rng)
    Dim s, sep, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            s = s & sep & c.Value
            sep = ","
        End If
    Next c
    RangeToCSV = s
End Function
```